# $\gamma_n^1 \otimes \gamma_n^1$ is isomorphic to the trivial line bundle over $\mathbb{RP}^1$

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, vector-bundles

I have read that $\gamma_n^1 \otimes \gamma_n^1$ is isomorphic to the trivial line bundle over $\mathbb{RP}^1$, where $\gamma_n^1$ is the canonical line bundle over $\mathbb{RP}^1$, but I am unable to give a vector bundle isomorphism.

I am ok with the fibers being 1-dimensional, but without a trivialization I really don't know how to get a map to $\mathbb{RP}^1 \times \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Do you know the cocycle associated to $\gamma^1_n$ ?

Comment: Up to isomorphism, there are only two line bundles over $S^1$. So, for every line bundle $E\to S^1$, the tensor product $E\otimes E$ is isomorphic to the trivial line bundle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $\gamma^1$ has total space

$$E(\gamma^1)=\{([x,y],(a,b))\in\mathbb{R}P^1\times\mathbb{R}^2\mid [x,y]=[a,b]\in\mathbb{R}P^2\},$$

and the bundle structure is given by projecting onto the first factor. It follows therefore that

$$E(\gamma^1\otimes\gamma^1)=\{([x,y],(a,b)\otimes(c,d))\in\mathbb{R}P^1\times\mathbb{R}^2\otimes\mathbb{R}^2\mid [x,y]=[a,b]=[c,d]\in\mathbb{R}P^2\}.$$

Since $\gamma^1\otimes\gamma^1$ is $1$-dimensional, to give it a trivialisation it suffices to find a global non-vanishing section $s:\mathbb{R}P^1\rightarrow E(\gamma^1\otimes\gamma^1)$. Now, since $\mathbb{R}P^1\cong S^1/[(a,b)\sim(-a,-b)]$ is a quotient of $S^1$, we can represent any of its points $[x,y]$ by an element $(x,y)\in S^1\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2$. Such a representation is not unique, but there are exactly two elements in each coset. Namely $(x,y)$ and $(-x,-y)$.

Define

$$s[x,y]=([x,y],(x,y)\otimes (x,y))\in E(\gamma^1\otimes \gamma^1).$$

This is well-defined since

$$(-x,-y)\otimes(-x,-y)=(x,y)\otimes (x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\otimes\mathbb{R}^2,$$

from which we see that the definition of $s$ does not depend on the choice of reprsentative for the coset $[x,y]\in\mathbb{R}P^1$. Furthermore, $s$ is non-vanishing at each point of $\mathbb{R}P^1$. Thus it gives a global trivialisation of $\gamma^1\otimes\gamma^1$.